# Python: how to identify zip code between US and CANADA

Tags: python, django

I have a form where user can provide their `address` containing `zip` code as well.

E.g. -

1. V7J, North Vancouver East Central, BC (Canada)
2. 462 1st Avenue, New York, NY 10016 (USA)

With given address, In `python(django)` what is the right approach to identify a `country`?

I tried `regx` approach

US - `^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$`

CANADA - `^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$`

Or I can just look for any `alphabet` in zip to say its `canada`?

Comment: You can leave out the `{1}`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use third-party packages like `geopy`? In that case I can suggest you a work-around for your problem hopefully.